# How can I get the current sorting of an Excel worksheet rearranged i.e. sort by another field and resort by the first one?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have coded a macro which fills a column with an identifier for another column depending on the values.

e.g:

**Proposal**  | **Identifier**
12345323      | 1
12345323      | 1
12346872      | 2
87956141      | 3
98745323      | 4

My problem comes when the worksheet is sorted by any other column, as I assign the values based on the order of the field "proposal".

My idea to solve this is to get the current sorting of the worksheet rearranged to suit to my needs, and then re-sort it as it was before, but I couldn't find any way to do this.

Comment: code your sort in a function, then call it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Set up a column with the row number (and paste it as values) before anything is sorted.

2) When you sort according to your identifier, include the column with the row numbers in the range to be sorted.

3) Then you can re-sort on the column containing the original row numbers to get back to your original order.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Ok that was much much simpler than what I already had in mind. Thank you man!

Comment: Glad it was what you wanted. Can be useful in many ways, e.g. For deleting blank rows, you can do something like IF(A1="",-1,ROW()), then copy down, sort, delete the rows with -1 at the top and resort.